# using getEchoString to mask/hide password input?

Tags: java, passwords, mask

I'm new to Java and I'd like to ask how to mask/hide the user's password input. I would like the program to display an asterisk (*) every time the user will type anything so that the password will be hidden. My password program alone (without the masking) works. The user will input a password and only has 3 tries afterwards. I would like to mask whatever the user will type with an asterisk.

I researched on the internet on how to use the masking but I don't understand it. My program failed to mask numerous times. I'm really new to Java and if you guys will use some other codes not found in mine. Please explain it if possible. Thanks.

Here is my first code:
     import java.io.*;
     import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

```
 public class Capture_Password {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 BufferedReader loopin=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
 JPasswordField passwordFld = new JPasswordField();

 final double pinno=12345;
 double ca;
 String attempt;

 try
 {
 System.out.println("Please enter the 5-digit PIN code:");
 attempt=loopin.readLine();
 ca=Double.parseDouble(attempt);

  if(ca==pinno)
    {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have entered the correct PIN code!");
    }

  else
    { 
            for(int tryleft=3; tryleft>=0 && ca!=pinno; tryleft--)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered the wrong PIN code");
                System.out.println("You have " + tryleft + " try/tries left");

                System.out.println();

                if(tryleft==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was your last attempt, goodbye!");
                    }

                System.out.println();

                if(tryleft>0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the 5-digit PIN code:");
                    attempt=loopin.readLine();
                    ca=Double.parseDouble(attempt);
                }    

                if(ca==pinno)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have entered the correct PIN code!");
                    }

            }   

            }



  }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
 }
 }}
```

And here's the other one:

```
 public class JPasswordField{
  public String getEchoString(){

       return "*";

 }
 }
```

I really appreciate your help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its possible to display asterisk in a system console from a java program but its definitely possible to simply disable displaying output.

Using the Console object in java, you can invoke the readPassword() method which, like in most unix systems, simply displays nothing when the user is typing in a password.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Capture_Password{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final char[] pinno = "12345".toCharArray(); //For high-security applications, this should be replaced with a method that uses temporary mutable objects to store passwords.
        char[] attempt;

        Console c = System.console();

        if(c != null){
            attempt = c.readPassword();

            if(Arrays.equals(attempt, pinno)){
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You have entered the correct PIN code!");
            }else{
                for(int tryleft=3; tryleft>=0 && !Arrays.equals(attempt, pinno); tryleft--){
                    System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered the wrong PIN code");
                    System.out.println("You have " + tryleft + " try/tries left");

                    System.out.println();

                    if(tryleft==0){
                        System.out.println("That was your last attempt, goodbye!");
                    }

                    System.out.println();

                    if(tryleft>0){
                        System.out.println("Please enter the 5-digit PIN code:");
                        attempt = c.readPassword();
                    }

                    if(Arrays.equals(attempt, pinno)){
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have entered the correct PIN code!");
                    }
                }
            }

            Arrays.fill(attempt, '0'); //Security measure, blanking the attempt
        }else{
            System.err.println("Error: No console");
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this code may fail to run within IDEs such as Eclipse (prints out 'Error: No Console') due to the way IDEs compile and run programs. To test out console based programs accurately, please compile and run it within a actual system console (Command Prompt, Terminal, etc).

Answer (score 0):

#### hey why dont you use swing frame work#### see an example it will help

```
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
  class Experiment 
 {
    /*declaration */

        JFrame frame; 
        JPanel panel;
        JLabel label1, label2, label3;
        JTextField tf1;
        JPasswordField tf2;
        JButton button;
        String S1,S2,S3,S4;


        /*declaration ended */


Experiment()
    {




        /*memory initialization */

        frame = new JFrame("Eraser");
        panel = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel("Sentence 1");
        label2 = new JLabel("What to Erase");
        label3 = new JLabel("");
        tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        tf2 = new JPasswordField(20);
        button = new JButton("Erase");


       /*memory initialization ended */



        /*containment*/

                frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                panel.add(label1);
                panel.add(tf1);
                panel.add(label2);
                panel.add(tf2);
                panel.add(label3);
                panel.add(button);


        /*containment ended*/

    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
    int frame_width = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
    int frame_height= ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  

/*button-configuration*/
     button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            buttonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });


 /*close-button-configuration*/


/* open - frame configuration */
    frame.setLocation(frame_width/2 - 125, frame_height/2 - 65);

    frame.setSize(250,190);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    /* close - frame configuration */










     }
    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    /*LOGIC*/


            S1= tf1.getText();
            S2= tf2.getText();


            S3 = S1.replace(S2,"");

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,S3);


            /*LOGIC ENDED   */
  }


  public static void main (String[]args)throws Exception 
  {

     Experiment object = new Experiment();





  }
}
```

**###  if you insist on using console then read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29 You'll have to be running at least Java 6 though.
.this doesn't work with the Eclipse console#####**